# I cant set ON UPDATE for unix_timestamp for INT datatype

Tags: sql, mysql, datetime, unix, timestamp

MySQL, I want to make attribute "updated_at" using UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), So everytime i update the table, the updated_at will automatically updated.

smthg like this;

```
column_name BIGINT NOT NULL DEFAULT UNIX_TIMESTAMP() ON UPDATE UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
```

But i know that we cant use ON UPDATE in INT data type

(I know that i can also INSERT INTO for that attribute manually, but i wish another solution)

I know about CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, but in this case, i want to store the value in unix time for performance and convert reason.

Also from what i heard that TIMESTAMP data type is stored as integer in mysql but in the interface it will be shown as yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss is that true?

Do you have any alternative for this problem?

Know more about date time stamp in mysql

Comment: You'd store the data in the column of DATETIME or TIMESTAMP datatype. You'd retrieve the value of this column using UNIX_TIMESTAMP().

Comment: I need mysql to store unix for performance, not for retrieving unix time.

Comment: I predict that the difference in performance will be non-detectable (less that measuring accuracy).

Comment: `TIMESTAMP` is stored as something like an INT`.